# python3 mayavi in docker not installing

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, vtk, mayavi

I am trying to get mayavi working inside a docker container and originally I was starting my Dockerfile from continuumio/anaconda3. I did a "conda install mayavi" it would appear to install but as soon as I tried to import it or vtk for that matter I would get:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkRenderingOpenGL2Python'"

When I try installing it from pip3 it fails to install with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkOpenGLKitPython'"

I have tried it starting from centos:7 and get the same issues. I guess its worth mentioning that a conda search or pip search of these modules comes up blank. However I can install it outside of docker and everything goes fine.

If it helps, my current Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum install vim -y
RUN yum install python3 -y
RUN yum install python3-pip -y
RUN yum install python3-devel -y
RUN yum install gcc -y

#RUN pip3 install mayavi
#RUN pip3 install PyQt5

RUN mkdir /home/working
WORKDIR /home/working
```

I have been at this for some time now and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can take a look at [my binder repo fork](https://github.com/FelipeLema/mne-binder) in which you can load inline mayavi in jupyter notebooks.

Pasting the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/FelipeLema/mne-binder/blob/master/Dockerfile) here for posterity:

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:65761486d5d3

MAINTAINER Jean-Remi King <jeanremi.king@gmail.com>

# Install core debian packages
USER root
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -yq dist-upgrade \
    && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    openssh-client \
    vim \
    curl \
    gcc \
    && apt-get clean

# Xvfb
RUN apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    xvfb \
    x11-utils \
    libx11-dev \
    qt5-default \
    && apt-get clean

ENV DISPLAY=:99

# Switch to notebook user
USER $NB_UID

# Upgrade the package managers
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN npm i npm@latest -g

# Install Python packages
RUN pip install vtk && \
    pip install boto && \
    pip install h5py && \
    pip install nose && \
    pip install ipyevents && \
    pip install ipywidgets && \
    pip install mayavi && \
    pip install nibabel && \
    pip install numpy && \
    pip install pillow && \
    pip install pyqt5 && \
    pip install scikit-learn && \
    pip install scipy && \
    pip install xvfbwrapper && \
    pip install https://github.com/nipy/PySurfer/archive/master.zip

# Install Jupyter notebook extensions
RUN pip install RISE && \
    jupyter nbextension install rise --py --sys-prefix && \
    jupyter nbextension enable rise --py --sys-prefix && \
    jupyter nbextension install mayavi --py --sys-prefix && \
    jupyter nbextension enable mayavi --py --sys-prefix && \
    npm cache clean --force

# Try to decrease initial IPython kernel load times
RUN ipython -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; print(plt)"

# Add an x-server to the entrypoint. This is needed by Mayavi
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--", "xvfb-run"]
```