# How to start with (install) mayavi on Jupyter by Anaconda on Win10?

Tags: python, mayavi

**Question**
How to install **mayavi** module so that I can use it in Jupyter Notebook? I use Windows 10. For me it's a nightmare.

I use the latest Anaconda and in order not to break dependencies, I don't want to use PIP (I'm not sure if this sentence makes sense).

My understanding of the installation process is tiny, I don't understand much. Since I tried a lot of commands, maybe it'd be better to start everything from scratch, i.e. create new environment.

**About**
I'm just learning Python, especially matplotlib package. I need to visualise calculations. I managed to use it for 2d animations and 3d with one surface. Unfortunatelly, matplotlib is bad if multiple surfaces are plotted in the same coordinate system. I learned that mayavi is better for such graphs.

**My trials**
On the latest version of Python there was a problem, so I created a second environment and installed Python 3.6 there using Anaconda Navigator. Then I installed mayavi, using Anaconda Navigator as well. Then I installed missing packages. Now I'm stuck. When I run this code on Jupyter Notebook:

```
from mayavi import mlab
```

I get an error ('Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu' means 'The specified module could not be found'):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\vtkCommonCore.py in <module>
      4     # use relative import for installed modules
----> 5     from .vtkCommonCorePython import *
      6 except ImportError:

ImportError: DLL load failed: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-67847bc6bfd0> in <module>
----> 1 from mayavi import mlab

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py in <module>
     14 # Mayavi imports
     15 from mayavi.core.common import process_ui_events
---> 16 from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
     17 from mayavi.tools.figure import figure, clf, gcf, savefig, \
     18     draw, sync_camera, close, screenshot

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py in <module>
     22 # We can't use gcf, as it creates a circular import in camera management
     23 # routines.
---> 24 from .engine_manager import get_engine
     25 
     26 

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py in <module>
     11 # Local imports
     12 from mayavi.preferences.api import preference_manager
---> 13 from mayavi.core.registry import registry
     14 from mayavi.core.engine import Engine
     15 from mayavi.core.off_screen_engine import OffScreenEngine

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\registry.py in <module>
     14 
     15 # Local imports.
---> 16 from mayavi.core.metadata import Metadata, import_symbol
     17 
     18 # A logger for this module.

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\metadata.py in <module>
      9 # Enthought library imports.
     10 from traits.api import HasTraits, Str, Callable, Either, List, Instance
---> 11 from mayavi.core.pipeline_info import PipelineInfo
     12 
     13 

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\pipeline_info.py in <module>
     10 from traits.api import HasTraits, Enum, List
     11 
---> 12 from .utils import get_tvtk_dataset_name
     13 
     14 # The list of datasets supported.

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\utils.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import vtk
      3 from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
      4 from vtk.numpy_interface import algorithms as algs
      5 

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\vtk.py in <module>
     30     all_spec = importlib.util.find_spec('vtkmodules.all')
     31     all_m = importlib.util.module_from_spec(all_spec)
---> 32     all_spec.loader.exec_module(all_m)
     33 
     34     # import vtkmodules

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\all.py in <module>
      5 
      6 # --------------------------------------
----> 7 from .vtkCommonCore import *
      8 from .vtkCommonMath import *
      9 from .vtkCommonMisc import *

F:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\byuzycMayavi\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\vtkCommonCore.py in <module>
      7     # during build and testing, the modules will be elsewhere,
      8     # e.g. in lib directory or Release/Debug config directories
----> 9     from vtkCommonCorePython import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkCommonCorePython'
```

On the list of packages in Anaconda Navigator there is a tick sign next to vtk and vtk--PKG.
I googled [this site](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/no-module-named-vtkcommoncorepython-import-vtk/7039) and I tried the code I found there. However, all of them give errors (DLL load failed).

Some of the solutions on SO are for Linux, some of them are old and seem out of date. Some of them link to [this site](https://anaconda.org/search?q=access%3Apublic%20platform%3Awin-64%20mayavi), but I don't know what to do with this list.

Comment: Have you tried `conda install -c conda-forge mayavi` ?

Comment: @HMH1013, I've just created a new environment and run your command. Now running from mayavi import mlab gives an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'. I installed it (version 4.8.2) in Anaconda Navigator. Then I run from mayavi import mlab  once again and I get an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyface.action.schema'. My Anaconda Navigator shows that I've got pyface package installed version 7.3.0. What to do?

Comment: If you ran `conda install -c conda-forge mayavi` in a new environment and it installed without error, then seeing the import give `ModuleNotFoundError` would make me suspect that you haven't attached Jupyter to that environment properly before trying the import. You can install Jupyter into that environment, too, or connect it using `nb_conda`, see [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3311#issuecomment-406740348) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283836/jupyter-notebook-with-conda-environment-cant-find-sklearn#comment132851693_75283836).

Comment: I know from [here](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-binder/issues/2#issuecomment-510101235) that it isn't easy but it has been done. There's some alternatives listed [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/ipygany-jupyter-into-the-third-dimension-29a97597fc33) by the way. Maybe those are easier? (I'm actually surprised no one has connected mayavi use to [jupyter_rfb:Remote Frame Buffer for Jupyter](https://github.com/vispy/jupyter_rfb/), but maybe it isn't easy to do especially since a lot of the examples packed in the examples don't seem to work after you open a session via 'launch binder'.)

Comment: Plus [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59903103/8508004) shows it was maybe working in 2020 at launches from MyBinder. If this was still working it would give you a place to work with it inside Jupyter without you needing to install anything on your own system.

Comment: @Wayne, when I ran conda install -v conda-forge mayavi I get the following: Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done.

Comment: @Wayne When I ran python command and then import mayavi in the cmd.exe I get no warnings or errors, but when I ran from mayavi import mlab I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'. I see the problem is also outside jupyter.

Comment: I was hoping I could find somewhere it was working. The closest I got was using the Spyder-IDE repo and opening a demo session using an old version with SPyder version 4.0. I ended up just using IPython in a terminal, It seems like it wants to work but while the QT window opens when I run `mlab.test_plot#d()`, it never shows the plot even though it acts like it is working. The window just keeps being transparent. I was hoping to at least have it working somewhere for maybe to use or compare. It used to work in the Enthough Distribution of Python. I wonder if it still does?